# Using slice syntax to swap elements in list

Tags: python, list, swap, slice

I'm running into a bit of trouble with the following function.
I want to know how to achieve the examples given in the doc-string by using simple list methods.

```
# The values of the two jokers.
JOKER1 = 27
JOKER2 = 28


def triple_cut(deck):
  '''(list of int) -> NoneType
  Locate JOKER1 and JOKER2 in deck and preform a triple cut.\
  Everything above the first joker goes at the bottom of the deck.\
  And everything below the second joker goes to the top of the deck.\
  Treat the deck as circular.
  >>> deck = [1, 2, 27, 3, 4, 28, 5, 6, 7]
  >>> triple_cut(deck)
  >>> deck
  [5, 6, 7, 27, 3, 4, 28, 1, 2]
  >>> deck = [28, 1, 2, 3, 27]
  >>> triple_cut(deck)
  >>> deck
  [28, 1, 2, 3, 27]
  '''
  # obtain indices of JOKER1 and JOKER2
  j1 = deck.index(JOKER1)
  j2 = deck.index(JOKER2)
  # determine what joker appears 1st and 2nd
  first = min(j1, j2)
  second = max(j1, j2)
  # use slice syntax to obtain values before JOKER1 and after JOKER2
  upper = deck[0:first]
  lower = deck[(second + 1):]
  # swap these values
  upper, lower = lower, upper
```

When I run a list of int. containing 27 and 28, the function doesn't do anything to the list.
I have no idea what the problem is, could you guys help me out?

Comment: Well, you aren't returning anything from the function, so the function isn't actually *doing* anything. I'd start there.

Comment: You're not changing `deck` at all - you're merely rebinding the *names* `upper` and `lower`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to paste the pieces together again, like:

```
deck[:] = deck[second + 1:] + deck[first: second + 1] + deck[:first]
```

This replaces the entire deck (`deck[:] = ...`).  This is straightforward.  Try to get trickier at your own risk ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're making copies of half the deck, changing the variables they're assigned to (would have been easier to just assign them the way you wanted them in the first place)... and that's it. You don't join them back together or anything. You also don't have a middle slice (of the cards between the jokers).

Answer (score 0):

Assignment to a slice only works if you do it immediately. You can't save the slice and then assign to it.

```
deck[(second + 1):], deck[0:first] = deck[0:first], deck[(second + 1):]
```